# How to calculate a forecast

Tags: financial-literacy, calculation, accounting, forecasting

I've been looking around to know how to calculate a sales forecast for sales generated. Not profit/loss; only sales made.

[Oracle's calculation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26228_01/doc.93/e20706/ap_forcst_calc_ex.htm#WEAFC279) shows some examples but I'm not sure if that's the standard way to do the calculation. Is there a formula for forecasting? A special formula?

I do know you have to compare previous values with `x` but what is `x`? A percentage?

Comment: if you look at the methods detailed in that link you will notice that the majority are regressions of one type or another which is a standard way of extrapolating series data in statistics and is commonly used by quants and actuaries to generate a sales forecast, amongst other things. Their models will be more complex and in many variables.

Comment: what is the goal of the calculation? knowing that may be determine what sort of factor to use.

Comment: Think of it as:  being self employed, i need to determine how much money im expected to earn today or next week, based on how I performed in the past (last week, month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different methods and the link in your question does give a wide variety of them.

The basic method is to either:

- use the past as an indicator of the future and then use an algorithm to extrapolate the performance into the future.
- or state that the conditions have changed and the previous numbers have to be adjusted up or down to reflect the changes. What type of changes?: open new store or close a store; release a new product or end a popular product; have a competitor do something different;  go viral in positive way or a negative way.

Determining these adjustments and forecasting their impact is the the key.